# Batch Script to Download Video with youtube-dl and Convert with FFmpeg

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I'm trying to

1. Using a single `batch` script to
2. Download an `mp4` video using [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html)
3. Save the video's original title to a batch variable
4. Convert the video to `webm` with [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)

I want to keep the original title, so it needs to read the title with `youtube-dl`, save it to a variable, and use that variable for `FFmpeg` input/output filename.

---

#### CMD Batch

**1. Download Video**

```
youtube-dl -f best "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWNhqCHw0qc" -o "C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%%(title)s.mp4" --merge-output-format mp4
```

---

**2. Download Video using Loop**

This is used to save the title to a variable `%%a`.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('youtube-dl -f best "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWNhqCHw0qc" -o @"C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%%(title)s.mp4" --merge-output-format mp4') do (echo example)
```

---

**3. Final Script**
**Download Video, Save Title, Convert with FFmpeg**

Sorted

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    youtube-dl 
    -f best "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWNhqCHw0qc" 
    -o @"C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%%(title)s.mp4" 
    --merge-output-format mp4
    ')

do (ffmpeg -y 
    -i "C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%%a.mp4" 
    -c:v libvpx -b:v 1300K -crf 16 -pix_fmt yuv420p 
    -map 0:v:0? -sn 
    -c:a libvorbis -q:a 6 -ac 2 -map 0:a:0? 
    -f webm
    "C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%%a.webm"
    )
```

Inline

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('youtube-dl -f best "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWNhqCHw0qc" -o @"C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%%(title)s.mp4" --merge-output-format mp4') do (ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%%a.mp4" -c:v libvpx -b:v 1300K -crf 16 -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:v:0? -sn -c:a libvorbis -q:a 6 -ac 2 -map 0:a:0? -f webm "C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%%a.webm")
```

---

#### Error

Before the script can ever reach `FFmpeg`, `youtube-dl` fails to download the file. It says the file has already been downloaded, even when there is no file in the directory.

> [download] @C#\Users\Matt\Downloads\Color Balloons.mp4 has already
>   been downloaded

Comment: In a batch file, `FOR` variables must use two `%` symbols. Says so on the eighth line of the help file.  Also since the `%` symbol is a special character, if you need to use a literal `%` you must also double it to two `%` symbols.

Comment: @Squashman That's when using it in a file, when copy pasting into cmd it can use one `%`.

Comment: I'm sending this script over to cmd from another `C#` program, if I use two `%` it fails.

Comment: Yes.  I never said you couldn't do that.  That is why I quoted the help file. But you literally wrote `BATCH` how many times in your question and used the `BATCH-FILE` tag.

Comment: Then remove the word `batch` from your question and remove the `BATCH-FILE` tag.

Comment: I see, I can edit the question to use the file double `%`.

Comment: Why did you double all the percent symbols if you are not running the code from a batch file?

Comment: So I can reach more users with the batch-file tag. I can run this in a batch file or send it over to cmd with C#, it will do the same thing. I'm going to test it in a `.bat` before putting it in the full C# program. That way I don't have to re-compile the program every time I make a change when testing it.

Comment: Not sure why you have an `@` in your code: `-o @"C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%(title)s.mp4"`.  I also told you in a previous comment that literal uses of a percent symbol also need to be doubled.  That means you need two percent symbols for your Youtube-dl variables as well. `%%(title)s`

Comment: youtube-dl was giving an error until I added the `@`, but I've adjusted the script since then, I'll remove it and see what happens. I've updated the youtube-dl `%`.

Comment: @Squashman I was able to create a working script, let me know what you think. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a script that works.

One of the problems was that `youtube-dl` wasn't working properly if located in `C:\Program Files\`, but works when located somewhere that doesn't require Administrator Privileges.

The `--get-filename` part requires an `@` symbol before the `youtube-dl` path.

---

1. `youtube-dl` gets filename from video and saves to var `%%f`
2. `youtube-dl` downloads the video to `C:\Path\To\Downloads\`
3. Merge output as `mp4`, so you can specify the extension for `FFmpeg` input
4. `FFmpeg` converts video to webm and uses `%%f` as input/output filename.

---

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('
    @"C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\youtube-dl.exe" 
    --get-filename -o "%%(title)s" 
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWNhqCHw0qc"
    ') 

do ("C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\youtube-dl.exe" 
    -f best "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWNhqCHw0qc" 
    -o "C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%%f.mp4" 
    --merge-output-format mp4 

    && 

    ffmpeg -y 

    -i "C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%%f.mp4" 
    -c:v libvpx 
    -b:v 1300K -crf 16 
    -pix_fmt yuv420p 
    -map 0:v:0? 
    -sn 
    -c:a libvorbis 
    -q:a 6
    -map 0:a:0? 
    -f webm 
    "C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\%%f.webm"
   )
```

Comment: You are doing something wrong if FFMpeg doesn't work after the `DO`.  I have helped all kind of people use FFMpeg and it has never been a problem before.

Comment: @Squashman I've adjusted the script, it looks like everything is working inside the `DO` now.